# How to batch process a folder of videos using MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

I wrote a MoviePy script that takes an input video, does some processing, and outputs a video file. I want to run this through an entire folder of videos. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Here's what I tried...

```
for f in *; do python resize.py $f; done
```

and resize.py source code here:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip(input)

clip1 = clip.rotate(270)

clip2 = clip1.crop(x_center=540,y_center=960,width=1080,height=608)

clip3 = clip2.resize(width=1920)

clip3.write_videofile(output,codec='libx264')
```

Really wasn't sure what to put for "input" and "output" in my .py file.

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 4):

I know you have an answer [on Github](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/542#issuecomment-293735347), but I'll add my own solution.

First, you'll want to put your code inside a function:

```
def process_video(input):
    """Parameter input should be a string with the full path for a video"""

    clip = VideoFileClip(input, output)

    clip1 = clip.rotate(270)

    clip2 = clip1.crop(x_center=540,y_center=960,width=1080,height=608)

    clip3 = clip2.resize(width=1920)

    clip3.write_videofile(output,codec='libx264')
```

Then, you can have a function that returns a list of file paths, and a list of final file names to use with the above function (note that the final file names will be the same as the original file names but with "output" in front):

```
import os
def get_video_paths(folder_path):
    """ 
    Parameter folder_path should look like "Users/documents/folder1/"
    Returns a list of complete paths
    """
    file_name_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

    path_name_list = []
    final_name_list = []
    for name in file_name_list:
        # Put any sanity checks here, e.g.:
        if name == ".DS_Store":
            pass
        else:
            path_name_list.append(folder_path + name)
            # Change the format of the output file names below
            final_name_list.append(folder_path + "output" + name)  
    return path_name_list, final_name_list
```

Finally, at the bottom, we get the input folder, and utilise the above two functions:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_folder = input("What folder would you like to process? ")
    path_list, final_name_list = get_video_paths(video_folder)
    for path, name in zip(path_list, final_name_list):
        process_video(path, name)
    print("Finished")
```

Just watch out, because this will crash if there are any files in the folder that can't be read as a movie. For instance, on mac, the OS puts a ".DS_Store" file in each folder, which will crash the program. I've put an area for a sanity check to ignore certain filenames.

Complete code:

```
import os

from moviepy.editor import *


def process_video(input, output):
    """Parameter input should be a string with the full path for a video"""

    clip = VideoFileClip(input)

    clip1 = clip.rotate(270)

    clip2 = clip1.crop(x_center=540,y_center=960,width=1080,height=608)

    clip3 = clip2.resize(width=1920)

    clip3.write_videofile(output,codec='libx264')


def get_video_paths(folder_path):
    """ 
    Parameter folder_path should look like "Users/documents/folder1/"
    Returns a list of complete paths
    """
    file_name_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

    path_name_list = []
    final_name_list = []
    for name in file_name_list:
        # Put any sanity checks here, e.g.:
        if name == ".DS_Store":
            pass
        else:
            path_name_list.append(folder_path + name)
            final_name_list.append(folder_path + "output" + name)
    return path_name_list, final_name_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_folder = input("What folder would you like to process? ")
    path_list, final_name_list = get_video_paths(video_folder)
    for path, name in zip(path_list, final_name_list):
        process_video(path, name)
    print("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

I responded on your [Github issue #542](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/542#issuecomment-293843765), but I copied it here for future reference!

First off, the below example isn't ironclad, but it should do what you need.
You can achieve this via something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Convert all media assets located in a specified directory."""
import glob
import os
from optparse import OptionParser

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip


def get_dir_files(dir_path, patterns=None):
    """Get all absolute paths for pattern matched files in a directory.

    Args:
        dir_path (str): The path to of the directory containing media assets.
        patterns (list of str): The list of patterns/file extensions to match.

    Returns:
        (list of str): A list of all pattern-matched files in a directory.
    """
    if not patterns or type(patterns) != list:
        print('No patterns list passed to get_dir_files, defaulting to patterns.')
        patterns = ['*.mp4', '*.avi', '*.mov', '*.flv']

    files = []
    for pattern in patterns:
        dir_path = os.path.abspath(dir_path) + '/' + pattern
        files.extend(glob.glob(dir_path))

    return files

def modify_clip(path, output):
    """Handle conversion of a video file.

    Args:
        path (str): The path to the directory of video files to be converted.
        output (str): The filename to associate with the converted file.
    """
    clip = VideoFileClip(path)
    clip = clip.rotate(270)
    clip = clip.crop(x_center=540, y_center=960, width=1080, height=608)
    clip = clip.resize(width=1920)

    clip.write_videofile(output, codec='libx264')
    print('File: {} should have been created.'.format(output))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = 'Failed!'
    parser = OptionParser(version='%prog 1.0.0')
    parser.add_option('-p', '--path', action='store', dest='dir_path',
                      default='.', type='string',
                      help='the path of the directory of assets, defaults to .')

    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    print('Running against directory path: {}'.format(options.dir_path))
    path_correct = raw_input('Is that correct?').lower()

    if path_correct.startswith('y'):
        dir_paths = get_dir_files(options.dir_path)
        for dir_path in dir_paths:
            output_filename = 'converted_' + os.path.basename(dir_path)
            modify_clip(path=dir_path, output=output_filename)

        status = 'Successful!'

    print('Conversion {}'.format(status))
```

With the above example, you can simply drop that into the directory of assets you wish to convert and run: `python this_file.py` and it should convert the files for you in the same directory with the name prepended with: `converted_`

Likewise, you can drop that file anywhere and run it against an absolute path:
`python this_file.py -p /Users/thisguy/media` and it will convert all files with the extensions: `['*.mp4', '*.avi', '*.mov', '*.flv']`

Either way, let me know if you have any questions (or if this resolves your issue) and I'll do my best to help you out!

Thanks for using moviepy!